# How to Embed A Fragment in My Custom View

Tags: android, fragment, android-custom-view, android-library

I am trying to create my first library, which will give a custom view `PDF`. I have defined it as styleable as follows:

```
<declare-styleable name="PDF">
        <attr name="background" format="integer"/>
        <attr name="contentDescription" format="string"/>
    </declare-styleable>
```

The class is defined like this:

```
public class PDF extends View {

    private int mBackgroundRes;

    public PDF(Context context, @Nullable AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
        TypedArray a = context.getTheme().obtainStyledAttributes(
                attrs,
                R.styleable.PDF,
                0,
                0);

        try{
            mBackgroundRes = a.getInteger(R.styleable.PDF_background, R.drawable.pdf);
            setBackgroundResource(mBackgroundRes);
        } finally {
            a.recycle();
        }

    }

}
```

I have a fragment class that is supposed to be displayed inside this new view. The first problem is that the view is not recognized in my application's layout, even when I provide its fully qualified name. The second problem is that I don't know how to inflate my fragment inside the custom view. Do I have to create another layout and add the fragment inside my custom view's tag and then inflate that layout? Which methods of the View class should I override?
For full code please see the project's [Github page](https://github.com/djnotes/PDF).

Comment: "I have a fragment class that is supposed to be displayed inside this new view" -- that is not possible. A `View` itself cannot display a fragment, and a `View` does not have a view hierarchy as its contents (the way a `ViewGroup` does). "The second problem is that I don't know how to inflate my fragment inside the custom view" -- you rewrite this custom `View` to be a custom `ViewGroup`, with appropriate rules for sizing and positioning its children. Then, have an activity or fragment add a fragment to your custom `ViewGroup`.

Comment: @CommonsWare How can I encapsulate this ViewGroup along with its fragment and provide it as a library for a custom view e.g. MyPDFView?

Comment: Again, a `View`/`ViewGroup` cannot display a fragment itself. Activities and fragments can display fragments.